# Cut a file and send it another folder in java

Tags: java, swing, paste

In java desktop application my I have used cut button;when it's clicked there should occur cut operation.In this code there is not generated wrong message.but when I run the project it shows that cut process has been proceed.But it does not work correctly,my code is given below:
// For cut

```
  String sourceLocation= "";
    String destLocation="";
    String fileCopyCmd="";
    Process  shortcutCpyprs=null;
    sourceLocation="E:\\data.txt";
    destLocation="G:\\";
    fileCopyCmd="cut \"" + sourceLocation + "\" \"" + destLocation + "\"";
    System.out.println(fileCopyCmd);
        try {
            shortcutCpyprs = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{"cmd", "/c", fileCopyCmd});
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(DesktopApplication2View.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
```

Comment: Did you run you application as an administrator?

Comment: No.This code executed only press a button in NetBeans desktop application

Comment: Try to run as an administrator. I think you don't have the privileges to do when you run as a user...

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/javadocs/api-2.4/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html#moveFile(java.io.File,%20java.io.File) ?

Using Java for such operations will give you access to any exceptions that could occur.

Comment: Also will give multiplatform support.